# Como coloco uma tag <h4> (já existente em um site) dentro de uma tag <a> (que eu vou criar com javascript)?

Tags: javascript

Então, eu quero coloca essa tag `<h4>exemplo1</h4>` que está em um site.

Dentro de um `<a href="exemplolink"></a>` que eu criaria em javascript através de uma extensão.

Exemplo de como eu quero que fique

```
    <a href="exemplolink"><h4>exemplo1</h4></a>
```

E quero que ela fique no mesmo lugar e com o mesmo conteúdo. [Meu problema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoRIk.jpg).

Answer (score -2):

Você pode colocar a tag com o link dentro da tag h4.

```
<h4><a href="exemplolink">exemplo1</a></h4>
```

Comment: mas como eu coloco o <a> dentro do <h4> com js, eu não conheço quase nada de html e js.

Comment: Consegui usando o .outerHTML.